# Is parseFloat safe in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, floating-point

In databases for store prices shouldn't use float type (should be decimal). So is in JavaScript `parseFloat()` safe for prices?

For example I have array with 1000000 numbers and I would like parse all to float and do various operations throughout the set and in the whole.

Comment: Floats are floats so the same caveats apply, in JavaScript 0.1+0.2 is not 0.3.  As 10 + 20 is 30 its best not to deal with fractional currencies at all and use whole integer small currency units.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "safe", but in general you shouldn't use floating-point math for prices. `parseFloat` only guarantees that the resulting floating-point number is the nearest IEEE double according to "round to nearest, ties to even" rounding mode. In most cases, this will result in a small rounding error:

```
> parseFloat("0.11").toFixed(40)
< "0.1100000000000000005551115123125782702118"
```

Further mathematical operations will increase the rounding error. If you make sure to round the final result to two decimal places with `toFixed(2)`, you should get the expected result in most cases. But this isn't guaranteed:

```
> parseFloat("1.37") * 90 * 90 * 90 * 90 * 90 * 90 * 90 * 90
< 5897400777000001
```

Unless you really know what you're doing, work with integer values of the smallest currency unit to be on the safe side. Note that JavaScript's number type can only store integers [up to 2<sup>53</sup> exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin).